# How do I use toyaml with a default empty/null value?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I really want to avoid an "if" condition because this feels like something that could be handled in a more readable way.

I have a value like this:

```
healthChecks:
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /
      port: http
```

And use it like this:

```
{{- toYaml .Values.healthChecks | nindent 10 }}
```

But the value might be empty and I want to support that. So if the value `healthChecks:` isn't specified the chart doesn't render it. How do I do this?

I was hoping toYaml would be smart enough to see .Values.healthChecks is empty and not do anything but it throws an error: `unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line X: could not find expected ':'`

Do I seriously need an if condition for this? Is there a built in way to just have toYaml do nothing if a value is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to avoid a conditional, you can use `default` to provide some sort of default value that can get rendered.  For example, using `dict` to produce an empty dictionary should render to `{}` inside the template.

```yaml
        healthChecks:
{{ .Values.healthChecks | default dict | toYaml | indent 10 }}
```

I probably would use a conditional here, which will have the particular advantage that you can avoid emitting the key if the value isn't present.  Using `with` instead of `if` will also mean you don't need to repeat the value (but has the downside that it changes the meaning of `.`, if you need to refer to other top-level values).

```yaml
{{ with .Values.healthChecks }}
        healthChecks: {{- toYaml . | nindent 10 }}
{{- end }}
```